# SQL - no database selected

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using a prepared statement to return items from a database, however when i execute it a no database selected error is thrown.

```
public void getTheMarketData() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName());
    PreparedStatement returnMarketData = con.prepareStatement
    ("SELECT  dealer_table.Dealer_Name, standard_dealer_link.*, standards_table.Standard_Value"
    + "FROM project.standard_dealer_link"
    + "inner join dealer_table on standard_dealer_link.DealerID = dealer_table.DealerID"
    + "inner join standards_table on standard_dealer_link.StandardID = standards_table.StandardID"
    + "where standard_dealer_link.Quarter= " + this.Quarter
    + "and dealer_table.Market = '" + this.Market + "';");
    ResultSet marketRS = returnMarketData.executeQuery();
```

Is there something really simple that i am missing? This exact format worked for my other statements.

Comment: Please do not use prepared statement with concatenated SQL string. It is straight way to SQL Injection attacks. Use named or positional [parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) instead.

Comment: select the database in you connect URL

Comment: @Jonty before firing query you need to establish connection to the database.

Comment: @Jonty take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm. You will get a clear idea what to do.

Comment: @androidGenX I thought 'Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();'  was what established the connection

Comment: it may help, when i call DBConnection.getConnection();:                   public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
             SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName(driver); 
            return (DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password));
    }

Comment: @Jonty  did you read the tutorial carefully? Just try it, it is what you needed. Error comes because you are not giving databasename, password, url for jdbc correctly. If you need more clarification please feel free to ask. Read tutorial and try it same with just changing your dbname and password